# Vue Computed Value Filter (script setup)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

I can't find anything relevant online. The relevant answers online dont use the  tag.
Does it even work with script setup?

```
<template>
  <div class="bg-white md:container md:mx-auto w-10">
    <ul class="flex flex-wrap p-2 justify-center bg-black text-white">
      <li class="p-2">
        <a href=""> Filter </a>
      </li>
      <li class="p-2">
        <a href=""> Search </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center h-52 content-center">
      <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="mb-3 xl:w-96">
          <label
            for="exampleSearch2"
            class="form-label inline-block mb-2 text-gray-700"
            >Search</label
          >
          <input
            v-model="searchValue"
            type="search"
            class="form-control block w-full px-3 py-1.5 text-base font-normal text-gray-700 bg-white bg-clip-padding border border-solid border-gray-300 rounded transition ease-in-out m-0 focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none"
            id="exampleSearch2"
            placeholder="Type query"
          />
          <div class="flex flex-wrap">
            <div>Test: {{ searchValue }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid lg:grid-cols-4 md:grid-cols-3 gap-8">
      <dogCard v-for="breed in breedsArray" :key="breed.id" :breed="breed" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import dogCard from "../components/dogCard.vue";
import { ref, onMounted, computed } from "vue";
import searchBox from "./searchBox.vue";

let URL = "https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds";
const searchValue = ref("");
let breedsData = ref([]);

// Fetching API Data
function getBreedsArray() {
  fetch(URL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      breedsData.value = data;
      console.log("Data Fetched", breedsData.value);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
onMounted(() => {
  getBreedsArray();
});

const breedsArray = computed({
  get() {
    return breedsData.value;
  },
  set(val) {
    breedsData.value = breedsData.value.filter((breed) => breed.name.includes() == searchValue);
  },
});
let isVisible = ref(false);
</script>
```

Im trying to filter the dogCard through a Searchbox. I just don't know how to do it.
The Data of 'breedsData' should change on when something is entered in the Searchbox.
Thanks in advance, I'm stuck for so long now, an i dont how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `filter()` in the computed setter, you do:

```
(breed) => breed.name.includes() == searchValue
```

But you probably want to use the value of the ref instead of the ref itself, and put it into `includes()`:

```
(breed) => breed.name.includes(searchValue.value)
```

Note that this would permanently remove filtered breeds, as you change the `breedsData.value`. A better approach might be to just use the computed getter (I don't think the setter works the way you want it to anyway):

```
const breedsArray = computed(() => searchValue.value ? 
  breedsData.value.filter( breed => breed.name.includes(searchValue.value)) :
  breedsData.value
)
```

Since `searchValue` is reactive, a change to it will trigger an update of the `breedsArray`.